# Copy folder from Windows host OS into Docker image using COPY in Docker file

Tags: windows, docker, copy

I want to copy folder `D:\test` from my host OS (Windows) to my docker image.

My Docker file is D:\Programs>

**Docker file**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN mkdir root
RUN cd root
WORKDIR /root
RUN mkdir test
COPY D:/test to /root/test
    #USING 'COPY' here instead of 'ADD' because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958140/what-is-the-difference-between-the-copy-and-add-commands-in-a-dockerfile
```

From folder D:\Programs> I run command `docker build . -t test`

But I get error:

> COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat test: file does not exist

I tried commands `COPY D:/test to /root/test` and `COPY ./test to /root/test`

I know this error occurs because the path I copy from has to be relative from the build context (the . in docker build .). It cannot be an arbitrary path on the system outside of the build context.

I thought by using `.` I'd be in context `D:\` from my build context `D:\Programs>`, but I guess not. What should my COPY command look like?

I checked here already:

- https://forums.docker.com/t/copy-files-from-windows-host-to-ubuntu-container/28757
- [Dockerfile COPY from a Windows file system to a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309423/dockerfile-copy-from-a-windows-file-system-to-a-docker-container/46309909)
- [Dockerfile: Copy directory from Windows host to docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382636/dockerfile-copy-directory-from-windows-host-to-docker-container)

**UPDATE 1**

I placed the `test` folder in `D:\Programs` where my Dockerfile also resides, so I now have structure:

```
D:\Programs
    \Test
    Dockerfile
```

I then ran the build command again where I tried `COPY test to /root/test` and `COPY ./test to /root/test`, but both fail with the same aforementioned error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you've only added `to` in `COPY D:/test to /root/test` for abbreviation but I recommend checking that anyway.

If you really need what's in `D:/Programs` and can't move it to a folder inside the current build context there are two general options as I see it:

1. changing the build context - I'd suggest setting the build context as `D:/` and adding every folder in the `D:/` directory other than `Programs` to the `.dockerignore` file, then you can reference the Dockerfile from some subdirectory somewhere in `D:/` and copy your files at build time as you wanted
2. creating a bind mount in runtime - you can map the `D:/Programs` directory to a folder inside the container (`/my-programs`) at runtime then copy the files from that folder to `/root/test` or just use the bind mount folder (`/my-programs`)

If in the future it will be available to use bind mounts in build time you'd be able to use the second option while creating the docker image

Comment: See my update 1, I already tried moving what I need into my build context but still it does not work

Comment: as I understood it from update 1 you ran the `docker build` command from `D:\Programs\test` (with that folder as build context), was I wrong?

Comment: I see how my update  was confusing. But yes, you were wrong, see updated update 1

Comment: ok, but the structure was clear, what folder did you set as your build context when running `docker build`?

Comment: From my post: "From folder D:\Programs> I run command `docker build . -t test`", so with the `.` parameter my build context is `D:\Programs` then, right?

Comment: and what was your `COPY` command that time? I'd presume `COPY . /root/test` to copy all the program files from the `D:\Programs` dir (which is the build context this time) but making sure nonetheless

Comment: Wow...It was a typo! I had `to` in my `COPY` command the whole time. Instead of `COPY test to /root/test` I had to use `COPY test /root/test`. Your sample COPY command pointed me to it. Just use that as your answer and I'll award the bounty

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do this is to change the dockerfile location during build, keeping the copied folder in context.

As below:

- 'test' folder located at `D:/test`
- Set dockerfile COPY command as such:

  `COPY test /root/test`
- Say dockerfile is at `D:/Programs/dockerfile`
- Navigate to `D:/` in CLI
- `docker build -f ./Programs/dockerfile .`

The `.` keeps the "test" folder in the build context. As far as I know, you cannot go to a parent directory etc. with docker build, so instead you want to stay in the parent folder and go down to the dockerfile.

Comment: Have tested again with your same folder structure from the update which definitely works on my machine. Running ```docker build .``` inside ```D:\Programs``` should copy "test" in providing:

- folder "test" is inside D:\Programs
- ```COPY test /root/test``` is in the dockerfile

Just to check, is your folder capitalisation the same? You've referenced "Test" and "test" in a couple of places, so worth asking. Also, you've added "to" in your COPY commands above, I assume that is not in your dockerfile COPY command and just for this post?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the `docker build ...`  from `D:\Programs` that folder is the docker build context. All files used in the Dockerfile must be there.

`d:\files` is outside `d:\programs`, so it will be never be found.

You need to copy `files` content to the places where you run the command and you can use this copy line

```
COPY samplefile1.txt /root/test
```

Comment: Thanks. Please see my update 1, I copied the folder to the build context but still get the same error